# Retrieve SMS code sent to user's phone - Firebase SMS Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to get the actual code that was sent by Firebase to the user.

I tried using the following piece of code:

```java
PhoneAuthCredential credential = 
    PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationid, usercode);

String ActualCode = credential.getSmsCode();
```

However this doesn't seem to work, as it looks like `getSmsCode()` retrieves the code entered by the user.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. And you should be happy about it.

Such API creates a potential security vulnerability for your users. Bad usage could lead hackers accessing your users' data. So it's a good decision by Google to not expose it.

However, if you're trying to achieve an Auto Sign-in functionality, know that on some devices Google Play services automatically detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without user action.

Read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#onverificationcompletedphoneauthcredential) about the Auto Retrieval mechanism of Firebase SMS Auth.

Answer (score 0):

```
private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential credential) {

            final String code = credential.getSmsCode();
            if (code != null) {

                PhoneAuthCredential authCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationID, code);
                firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,
                                    "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    enter code here
        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Verification Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s,
                               @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {

            super.onCodeSent(s, token);
            verificationID = s;
        }
    };
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).